# Can the CyberSource TMS API be used with a Flex API Token?

Tags: cybersource

The CyberSource Token Management Service (described [here](https://developer.cybersource.com/api/developer-guides/dita-tms/intro.html) and [here](https://developer.cybersource.com/api-reference-assets/index.html#token_management)) allows you to create "instruments" which are tokenized cards that can be stored with a user's account and used for later purchases/transactions with your service.

I would like to use the Flex API (described [here](https://developer.cybersource.com/api/developer-guides/dita-flex/SAFlexibleToken/FlexAPI.html), [here](https://developer.cybersource.com/api-reference-assets/index.html#flex#generate-key) and [here](https://github.com/CyberSource/cybersource-flex-samples-node)) to perform an initial tokenization of the card.  Can I then use a Flex token to perform TMS calls?

Obviously both mechanisms are tokenization, but there are advantages to both:

1. TMS seems intended for long-term storage and supports auto-superseding PANs.
2. Flex has the capability to switch to micro-form iframes.

So it would be useful to do the initial tokenization with Flex for PCI-DSS reasons, and then use that to create TMS tokens for long-term storage.

Comment: Hi Mat, 
Have you managed issue with persistent token creation from transient token without payment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Flex API can be used to create TMS tokens.

You can think of TMS (Token Management Service) as services to create, read, update, and delete tokens as well as the storage of those tokens. The purpose of Secure Acceptance Flex Microform and Flexible Token API is to reduce PCI scope when handling credit card account numbers by replacing them with tokens without touching your servers (direct from customer browser or app to CyberSource). The Secure Acceptance Flex Microform and Flexible Token API uses TMS underneath to create tokens, but cannot read, update, delete tokens or authorize the card.

Comment: Helpful data, thanks.  The answer is basically "no".

Answer (score 3):

@matt-mc,

To add to @will-h answer, although you can use Secure Acceptance Flex (microform & token) API to create 'transient' tokens for PCI scope reduction, you can 'make/transform' these for use in the TMS API by using the example shown in the developer center under Payments > Process a Payment > Sample Request: Payment with Flex Token (Create Permanent TMS token).

The payload will look something like this:

```
{
"clientReferenceInformation": {
    "code": "TC50171_3"
},
"processingInformation": {
    "actionList": [
        "TOKEN_CREATE"
    ],
    "actionTokenTypes": [
        "customer",
        "paymentInstrument",
        "shippingAddress"
    ]
},
"orderInformation": {
    "amountDetails": {
        "totalAmount": "102.21",
        "currency": "USD"
    },
    "billTo": {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "address1": "1 Market St",
        "locality": "san francisco",
        "administrativeArea": "CA",
        "postalCode": "94105",
        "country": "US",
        "email": "test@cybs.com",
        "phoneNumber": "4158880000"
    },
    "shipTo": {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "address1": "1 Market St",
        "locality": "san francisco",
        "administrativeArea": "CA",
        "postalCode": "94105",
        "country": "US"
    }
},
"tokenInformation": {
    "transientTokenJwt": "eyJraWQiOiIwODVLd3ZiZHVqZW1DZDN3UnNxVFg3RG5nZzlZVk04NiIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.eyJkYXRhIjp7Im51bWJlciI6IjQxMTExMVhYWFhYWDExMTEiLCJ0eXBlIjoiMDAxIn0sImlzcyI6IkZsZXgvMDgiLCJleHAiOjE1OTU2MjAxNTQsInR5cGUiOiJtZi0wLjExLjAiLCJpYXQiOjE1OTU2MTkyNTQsImp0aSI6IjFFMTlWWVlBUEFEUllPSzREUUM1NFhRN1hUVTlYN01YSzBCNTc5UFhCUU1HUUExVU1MOFI1RjFCM0IzQTU4MkIifQ.NKSM8zuT9TQC2OIUxIFJQk4HKeHhj_RGWmEqOQhBi0TIynt_kCIup1UVtAlhPzUfPWLwRrUVXnA9dyjLt_Q-pFZnvZ2lVANbiOq_R0us88MkM_mqaELuInCwxFeFZKA4gl8XmDFARgX1aJttC19Le6NYOhK2gpMrV4i0yz-IkbScsk0_vCH3raayNacFU2Wy9xei6H_V0yw2GeOs7kF6wdtMvBNw_uoLXd77LGE3LmV7z1TpJcG1SXy2s0bwYhEvkQGnrq6FfY8w7-UkDBWT1GhU3ZVP4y7h0l1WEX2xqf_ze25ZiYJQfWrEWPBHXRubOpAuaf4rfeZei0mRwPU-sQ"
}
```

}

Comment: Great, this is certainly useful! Do you know if you can make a permanent token out of a transient one without making a payment? I didn't find any TMS endpoint that accepts a flex token and a making a blank payment just to tokenize a card doesn't feel right...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tested it in the Cybersource sandbox environment and got the instrument identifier succesfully. However, when attempting the same in the production environment the permanent token was missing from the response even though the zero payment was authorized. Any idea what could be different between the sandbox and production environments?